# Can't generate Azure SAS connection string. Suspect this is " Some routing options are disabled because the endpoints are not published."

Tags: azure, publish, endpoint

Attempting to "Generate SAS and connection string" in Azure Shared access signature. The following message is present "Some routing options are disabled because the endpoints are not published."  The button "Generate SAS and connection string" is inactive. Is the button inactive because the endpoints are not published? There is one endpoint (ITLLCGlobal (ITLLCGlobal/ITLLCGlobal), service endpoint NQUEUE). If this is the cause how do I publish the endpoint?

Comment: Can you edit your question and include more details please around endpoints? Are you trying to create a SAS token from Azure Portal?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to create an SAS token but the button is grayed out.  The endpoint is ITLLCGlobal (ITLLCGlobal/ITLLCGlobal)

Comment: @Nate Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 11):

[image: Allowed Resource Types]

You can enable it by selecting one of the resource types. Services, Container, object

Answer (score 3):

In Shared access signature, make sure you have selected an "Allowed resoure type"

Either service, container or object.

That is all it took for me. I needed to do anything under Firewalls and Virtual networks yet.

Gina

Answer (score 3):

I also run into the issue. I solved it by selecting one or more 'Allowed Resource Type'

Answer (score 0):

My role was set to "owner" but needed to be set to the "storage blob data owner". I thought that owner granted all access but it does not. Once I changed to the correct role the routing options became active and changed to the correct option automatically.